# Why won't OR work in this regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code:

```
function toCamelCase(str){
var rest = str.replace((/-/)|(/_/)g, "") ;
  document.write(rest);  
}
toCamelCase("the-stealth_warrior");
```

I get  `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )` I want my regex to remove underscores and hyphens.

Comment: Seems to me that you missed `"` double quotes around regex.

Comment: Use string functions instead.

Comment: `var rest = str.replace(/[_-]/g, "") ;` You don't need that OR thingy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simple answer

```
function toCamelCase(str){
   var rest = str.replace(/[_-]/g, " "); 
   document.write(rest);
}

toCamelCase("the-stealth_warrior");
```

Comment: This! This is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

There are number of things which are wrong like escaping `/`, double quotes `"` etc. The correct version should be as following.

```
function toCamelCase(str){
  var rest = str.replace(/-|_/g, "") ;
  document.write(rest);
}
toCamelCase("the-stealth_warrior");
```

For quick test press `Ctrl+Shift+I` and paste this code in `Console.` I recommend using `alert` instead of `document.write` for testing purpose.

Comment: `-|_` -> `[-_]` That's what character classes are for :)

Comment: @Jan: That was stupid of me. I was in hurry to post answer. IYKWIM ;-)

Comment: IYKWIM? What does this mean?

Comment: You can at least remove the escaping: neither `-` nor `_` are special characters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I add then to avoid misinterpretation and forget to remove after adding in answer. So dumb of me !

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around the regex; this is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: I was drunk while giving this answer. So many mistakes ! Thank you magicians.